# Can't conda install multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, conda

I am trying to install multiprocessing in my conda environment. From anaconda's website: https://anaconda.org/auto/multiprocessing, to install multiprocessing I ran in my conda env:

```
conda install -c auto multiprocessing=2.6.2.1
```

However, I got this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - multiprocessing 2.6.2.1*
  - python 3.5*
```

Why is this so? Is multiprocessing not compatible with `python 3.5`? If so, is there a way to install a specific version of multiprocessing in conda environment that is compatible with python 3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Is multiprocessing not compatible with python 3.5?"_ - "The following specifications were found to be in conflict" is saying just that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://anaconda.org/auto/multiprocessing/files , *that version of* `multiprocessing` was indeed not written to be compatible with Python 3.

The fact that its page links to Google Code also means that it's long abandoned since that site has closed down a few years ago, and it's luck that even the archive is still there.

Speaking of which:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/python-multiprocessing/:

> This is a back port of the multiprocessing package introduced via
>   PEP-371 and Python 2.6. This is essentially for meta-fork of the
>   original pyprocessing project found at:
>   http://pyprocessing.berlios.de/

So, it's functionally equivalent to the [`multiprocessing` in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) introduced in Python 2.6, and you should use that.

The `conda info` for it says the same:

> Summary: Backport of the multiprocessing package to Python 2.4 and 2.5